# Currency Position changed after Sitecore upgrade from 8.1 to 9.3

Tags: upgrade, multilingual

We have a multisite and multilingual project. We upgraded it from `Sitecore 8.1` to `Sitecore 9.3`.
On one of the pages, we show prices e.g., $ 250.90.
Before the upgrade, the site used to show currency symbol before the price - $ 250.90.
But after the upgrade, it shows after the price - 250.90 $.

The logic to display the price with currency symbol takes the NumberFormatInfo object from the CultureInfo of the context language and uses this number format to determine the position of the currency symbol as per the `NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyPositivePattern` property.

```
public static string FormatDoubleAsCurrency(this double amount, Language language, string currency)
{
NumberFormatInfo nfi = language == null
? (NumberFormatInfo)Sitecore.Context.Language.CultureInfo.NumberFormat.Clone()
: (NumberFormatInfo)language.CultureInfo.NumberFormat.Clone();



nfi.CurrencySymbol = GetCurrency(currency);
return string.Format(nfi, "{0:c}", amount);
}
```

Can anybody please suggest what is the recommended way to handle this? Can the `numberformat/cultureinfo` be changed in Sitecore or does it require code change? If code change is required, please suggest a clean way to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: probably, the easiest solution is to specify `CurrencyPositivePattern` manually (in your case it should be set to 2, you can check it in [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern?view=net-6.0). To investigate the issue, maybe try to ensure, the culture is the same after upgrade. and also you can debug and compare `CurrencyPositivePattern` value. but with code changes, I would suggest the following:
`nfi.CurrencyPositivePattern = 2;`

Comment: @IgorZharikov Thank you for your answer. Is there any better way to do this?